# The object stops after a spawning

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I stop the object from running after spawning to checkpoint?

```
function OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider)
{
    if(col.tag =="Player")
    {
        SpawnPoint.position = Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: By running do you mean updating?

Comment: i mean is that i have a vehicle when i respawn it to my last checkpoint the vehicle is continue to run i want the car to stop after respawning to the last checkpoint

Comment: Running is a very generic term, do you mean it to stop moving? For the update loop to no longer run on that object? For the animation to pause on the first frame?

Comment: to stop moving the object

Comment: Are you moving it using a rigidbody or by changing its position yourself? Maybe post the part of your script that controls movement?

Comment: #pragma strict
var wheelFL : WheelCollider;
var wheelFR : WheelCollider;
var wheelRL : WheelCollider;
var wheelRR : WheelCollider;
var maxTorque : float = 50;

function Start(){
rigidbody.centerOfMass.y = -0.9;
}


function FixedUpdate () {
wheelRR.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelRL.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelFL.steerAngle = 20 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
wheelFR.steerAngle = 20 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

} here is my car script

Answer (score 1):

I found this over at [answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/35066/remove-all-forces-on-a-wheel-collider.html)

What you should do is briefly set the rigidbody to kinematic, as well as `brakeTorque` for all wheel colliders to `Mathf.Infinity` and than next update switch it back off and the physics engine should reset any forces causing it to move.

Example from link:

```
function FixedUpdate()
{
    // (if the vehicle has been respanwed this frame, 
    //        then a variable respawned is set to true)

    if (respawned)
    {
        wheelCol.brakeTorque = Mathf.Infinity;   // Repeat for all wheelcolliders
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        respawned = false;
    }
    else
    {
        rigidbody.isKinematic = false;

        // (do the torque calculations here as usual)
    }
}
```

Comment: where will I put it on my car script control or on the spawning codes?

Comment: Car script, so have a function clearForces that will do that for you

Comment: what will I put in the respawned?

Comment: So I have a Carcontrol Script where I put my controls and this is a new script? then I will call the carcontrol to this new script?

Comment: It can be, I don't really understand how difficult it could possibly be. Put the code I provided in the fixedupdate function of your car control script. Have a variable named respawn of type Boolean on the car control class. Set respawn to true from anywhere you like. Watch as your car no longer has any momentum.

Comment: Sir Shanon . it has no errors but after I hit the playbutton the object stops and my goal is when i get back to the checkpoint my car will suddenly stop but when I click again the gas button It will Run again

Comment: #pragma strict
var wheelFL : WheelCollider;
var wheelFR : WheelCollider;
var wheelRL : WheelCollider;
var wheelRR : WheelCollider;
var maxTorque : float = 50;
var respawned = true;

function Start(){
rigidbody.centerOfMass.y = -0.9;
}

Comment: function FixedUpdate () {
wheelRR.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelRL.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelFL.steerAngle = 20 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
wheelFR.steerAngle = 20 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

Comment: if (respawned)
    {
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        
        
    }
    else
    {
        wheelFL.brakeTorque = Mathf.Infinity; 
        wheelFR.brakeTorque = Mathf.Infinity;
        wheelRL.brakeTorque = Mathf.Infinity;  
        wheelRR.brakeTorque = Mathf.Infinity;// Repeat for all wheelcolliders
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        respawned = false;
        // (do the torque calculations here as usual)
    }

}

Comment: That is my whole script Car Script but on the starting point the car doesn't run . I need that the car run first then if I pass to a check point it will save me on the point there and my car will stop there but can be move again

Comment: The first if statement `if (respawned) { rigidbody.isKinematic = true; } ` should be `if (!respawned) { rigidbody.isKinematic = false; } `